# How to create a union of two lists and then iterate it

Tags: python, list, methods, iterator

I'm trying to create a union of the `self.list_my_str` with `new_list`and this new created list I want to iterate it. My attempt so far:

```
class Stringuri(): 
    list_my_str = []

    def __init__(self, my_str):
        self.my_str = my_str

    def strtolist(self):
        len_my_str = len(self.my_str)
        for i in range(0, len_my_str):
            self.list_my_str.append(self.my_str[i])
        return self.list_my_str

    def reversestr(self):
        new_list = self.list_my_str.copy()
        new_list.reverse()
        return new_list

    reunion = self.list_my_str.extend(new_list)

    def __iter__(self):
        all_series = []
        for i in reunion:
            all_series.append(i)
        return StringIterabil(all_series)

class StringIterabil():
    def __init__(self, series):
        self.series = series
        pass

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if not self.series:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            return self.series.pop(0)
```

Test code:

```
a = Stringuri('Ana are mere')
print(a.strtolist())
print("-----------")
print(a.reversestr())
print("-----------")
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

I'm a beginner in Python classes and any book, video or something else which will help me to understand better the classes are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a union of two lists and you don't want the same items to appear twice the best way would be to use sets.

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
list2 = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']
union_of_lists = list(set(list1).union(set(list2)))
```

Helpful tip: whenever you modify an object in python, for example using append() or extend() you modify the original object so saving the output in a new variable will give you a NoneType object.

```
# alternative way to combine two lists without removing duplicates
[i for i in list1 or list2]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is called string concatenation, you can do this with the `+` operator on two `str`:

```py
str_1 = "Hello, "
str_2 = "world!"
str_3 = str_1 + str_2
# str_3 = "Hello, world!"
```

You can also concatenate `str`'s in-place with `+=`:

```py
str_1 = "Hello, "
str_1 += "world!"
# str_1 = "Hello, world!"
```

If you want to reverse a `str`, you can use string slicing:

```py
s_1 = "abcd"
s_2 = s_2[::-1]
# s_2 = "dcba"
```